# regex: python to get string between parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, string, curly-braces

I need to fetch text between parenthesis `{` **text** `}` in python.
here is my sample string,

```
my_txt = "/home/admin/test_dir/SAM_8860-fg_frame_{001,002,003,004,005,007}.png"
```

I need numbers between **{}**.

I tried,

```
>>> re.search(r'{.*}',my_txt).group()
'{001,002,003,004,005,007}'
```

but it returns string along with curly braces.

expected output is, `'001,002,003,004,005,007'`

how to omit curly braces to fetch string in python regex?

Comment: `re.search(r'{(.*?)}',my_txt).group(1)`

Comment: `re.search(r'{.*}',my_txt).group().replace('{', '').replace('}', '')`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to expand the content in the braces, like bash does. If that's the case, [there exists a package for that](https://github.com/trendels/braceexpand)

Comment: Use lookbehind and lookahead: `re.findall('(?<={).+?(?=})',my_txt)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your comment it works as expected. and thanks for downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get only the [matched group](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group):

```
>>> re.search(r'{(.*?)}',my_txt).group(1)
'001,002,003,004,005,007'
```

- `group(0)` is the *entire* match
- `group(1)` is the first match
- ...

Comment: this works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it creates group and select 1st group

```
re.search(r'{(.*?)}',my_txt).group(1)
```